# Predict a pair of geographical coordinates from their equivalent in flat coordinates in Google Colab

Tags: python, google

I try to predict unknown geographic coordinates from meters coordinate in an excel table. (x and y). something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from math import radians
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

First I will connect to drive server

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Them, I get the data

```
import pandas as pd
link1 = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rOESJV89SzIDiQku88MsIXA6_WcyB0Ol'
wdir, id = link1.split('=')
id

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('data.xlsx')
print('The files was downloaded')

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=0)
df.columns = ['x','y','W','N']
df['Id'] = ['n_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(df))]
print(df.info())
df.head()
```

As you can see, I get missing data in W and N columns, that there is the geographic coordinate:

[image]

However, the columns x and y are complete. Is it possible to predict the N and W columns use x and y columns? I was using the next pace of code (lineal regression) for my propose:

```
sample = df[df.N.notnull() & df.W.notnull()].copy()

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

y = sample[['W','N']].values

X = sample[['x','y']].values

regr.fit(X,y)

r2_score(sample[['W','N']].values, regr.predict(sample[['x','y']].values))
```

If you gonna see my notebook this is the link:
[Notebook in Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qVDGAMnccz7I4X3p3gBL5fULPlbz6uEo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a problem with the data (sample DataFrame) because the distribution of points is very different between the xy coordinates (left figure) and the WN coordinates (right figure, the relations between points are not preserved)

```
plt.scatter(sample.x,sample.y,c='r', s= 12)
plt.scatter(sample.W,sample.N,c='r', s= 12)
```

[image][image]

Despite this problem a solution would be the to estimate the affine transformation parameters between the two sets of 2D points (with the sample DataFrame) and then predict the values for the other points (blue points below)

[image]

You can do the script yourself (as [Christoph Gohlke's transformations.py](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html) for example) or directly use solutions like  [Affine_Fit](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/affine-fit/), [nudged-py](https://github.com/axelpale/nudged-py) or  [affine6p](https://pypi.org/project/affine6p/) to predict the points.

**With Jarno Elonen  [Affine_Fit](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/affine-fit/):**

```
from_pt = sample[['x','y']].values
to_pt =   sample[['W','N']].values
trn = Affine_Fit(from_pt , to_pt)
# control of the parameters
err = 0.0
for i in range(len(from_pt)):
    fp = from_pt[i]
    tp = to_pt[i]
    t = trn.Transform(fp)
    err += ((tp[0] - t[0])**2 + (tp[1] - t[1])**2)**0.5

print("Fitting error = %f" % err)
Fitting error = 4.551783
```

Prediction

```
# select the empty W,E values of the original DataFrame
empty = df[df['W'].isnull()]
points = np.stack((empty.x,empty.y), axis=1)
for pt in points:
    print(trn.Transform(i))
[-74.65431    3.761869]
[-74.653086   3.763813]
[-74.651857   3.766015]
[-74.652259   3.765516]
....
```

[image][image]

**With affine6p**

```
import affine6p
trans = affine6p.estimate(from_pt , to_pt)
# the affine transformation matrix
trans.get_matrix()
[[-9.718141586567697e-06, -5.663279571255231e-05, -74.64881092190512],
[2.6117070488135274e-05, -9.465679085446377e-05, 3.767950125295915],
[0, 0, 1]]
```

Prediction

```
for pt in from_pt:
   print(trans.transform(pt))
[-74.65431    3.761869]
[-74.653086   3.763813]
[-74.651857   3.766015]
[-74.652259   3.765516]]
.....
```

The results are the same with all the solutions but seem strange (even if I change the W,N coordinates in degrees(?) to cartesian coordinates in meters)

[image]